# aws cdk, best practice for gathering information from aws account

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a AWS CDK Project which creates:

- a hosted zone in several accounts
- record sets for verifying my ACM certificates
- record sets needed by SES

For the creation of needed record sets for ACM and SES, I would like to get the information from AWS in an automated way.

But how can I dot this?

I could use boto3 (I am using AWS CDK for python) but I need to specify a profile for boto3 to make the calls. And since I am creating hosted zones in several accounts, this profile needs to be different for every stack.
Also sometimes I am creating stacks for one account and do not have any credentials available for other accounts. But

```
aws cdk deploy my-test-account-hosted-zone-stack
```

Generates the stacks for all accounts also it deploys only one stack in one account. So I need credentials for all accounts.

What is a best practice of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe that you need to edit your app to deploy each as a separate stack, each stack will get its own account and region.

for example:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from multistack.multistack_stack import MultistackStack

app = core.App()
MultistackStack(app, "MyWestCdkStack",
                env={
                     'account': 321, 
                     'region': 'us-west1-2'
                     },
                encrypt_bucket=False)

MultistackStack(app, "MyEastCdkStack",
                env={
                     'account': 12, 
                     'region': 'us-west1-2'
                     },
                encrypt_bucket=True)
```

[OFFICIAL DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/stack_how_to_create_multiple_stacks.html)  <--